# How to echo pieces of html from an external file on same folder?

Tags: php, echo

I want to create a lot more cleaner html document/template, which uses the echo command to call the pieces of html/scripts.

Though.. I can't find out how to get it working.

The document I want to reach is like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo 'header.html';
echo 'container.html';
echo 'footer.html';
?>
```

So this way I can edit each part of the website in an individual document, instead of all pieces of the site in one whole.

```
<?php
$myString = 'include(portfolio.php); '; 
echo $myString;
echo file_get_html('portfolio.php');
echo file_get_html('portfolio.html');
?>
```

(For trying, i've put a piece of HTML only coding in both a html and php document ( ?>) just for trying if that is any difference..)

But.. You all probably know: This ain't working.

So as simple as your answer could be:

How can I 'echo' a piece/everything within an external file, as in above: echo the 'portfolio.html' content.

Thanks!

p.s. I think echo is my best bet for 'pasting' external coding, but if you got a better, easier, more SEO solution: Be my guest!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use includes

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include 'header.html';
            include 'container.html';
            include 'footer.html';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I can't seem to get it working. Please check -> [link](http://umowe.nl/rider/index-2.html)

There should be a part with portfolio items and a category switcher, but you don't see them. But if you go [link](http://umowe.nl/rider/index-2/home_portfolio.html) you see the thing I try to include

Comment: Sander, your file needs to have a .php extension in order to use PHP in it. The link you sent was to an HTML document. Change it to .php and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Change the file that has the `<?php include 'filename'; ?>` code in it to .php

Answer (score 0):

Can't echo a file. 
use

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.html');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/container.html');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.html');
```